# bootstrap dropdown menu external link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation

my dropdown menu with bootstraps work but only with internal links. i want it to work with external links

www.speleobox.be/test

This is my code:

```
<!-- BEGIN NAVIGATION -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Huur uw... <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.speleobox.be">Speleobox</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.sumopak.be">Sumopakken</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#experience">Speleobox</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pricing-tables">Prijzen</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact-us">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see you have a custom code that scrolls to some anchor in the code. So this prevents default onclick events even for external links.

```
//smooth scroll to href value
jQuery(".tabs-btn ul li a, .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
 });
```

Also there is an error in the code that you can see in dev console

```
Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I suggest removing this code and swap it with this one
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This functions works great, I've used a bunch of times.